# What is $\sqrt{i^0+\sqrt{i^1+\sqrt{i^2+...}}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, complex-numbers, radicals, nested-radicals

$$\sqrt{i^0+\sqrt{i^1+\sqrt{i^2+...}}}=?$$
Where $i$ is the imaginary unit, $i=\sqrt{-1}$.
I just want to know whether this is possible or not.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried to write this as a limit of a sequence finite expressions? And have you tried to evaluate some of the terms of that sequence?

Comment: Complex square roots are multivalued. Unless you specify the branch this is far from well-defined.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer the limit notation in writing these expressions. Nevertheless, **if I have interpreted your notation correctly**, then you want something like this:

$L=\sqrt{i^0+\sqrt{i^1+\sqrt{i^2+\sqrt{i^3+\sqrt{i^4+\sqrt{i^5+...}}}}}}$

$\implies L^2-1=\sqrt{i^1+\sqrt{i^2+\sqrt{i^3+\sqrt{i^4+\sqrt{i^5+...}}}}}$

$\implies (L^2-1)^2-i=\sqrt{i^2+\sqrt{i^3+\sqrt{i^4+\sqrt{i^5+...}}}}$

$\implies ((L^2-1)^2-i)^2+1=\sqrt{i^3+\sqrt{i^4+\sqrt{i^5+...}}}$

$\implies (((L^2-1)^2-i)^2+1)^2+i=\sqrt{i^4+\sqrt{i^5+...}}=L$  (Recall that $i^4=1, i^5=i$ and so on)

At least in principle, you can get the answer by solving the equation.

**However, remember that complex square roots are multivalued and there is no such thing as a 'positive square root' for complex numbers as used in your notation.**

Hence, there still remains some ambiguity in the question and we get multiple answers by this method. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%28%28%28L%5E2-1%29%5E2-i%29%5E2%2B1%29%5E2%2Bi%3DL

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you think solving like an eight-degree polynomial is possible?

Comment: Yes, which doesn't mean that any conjured up polynomial will have pretty roots (however you define pretty).  This  has degree  $16$ btw.

Comment: @user712576 You can solve it, in principle. There are computer programs that can do the job pretty well for you, though I have never tried solving complex polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

Above equation shown below:

$L=\sqrt{i^0+\sqrt{i^1+\sqrt{i^2+\sqrt{i^3+\sqrt{i^4+\sqrt{i^5+...}}}}}}$  ----(1)

Equation (1) is equivalent to equation (2) below:

$L=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{i+\sqrt{-1+\sqrt{-i+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{i+...}}}}}}$  ----(2)

It is noted that the above number sequence alternates

between $(1,i)$ & $(-1,-i)$.

After simplification of the equation given

by @tatan & equating the coeeficent of $(i)$

to zero we get the below equation:

$(w-2)(w^2-2w+2)=0$  ----(3)

where, $w=L^2$

Solving equation (3),

we get, $L=(1+i)$

Answer (score -1):

Above equation shown below:

$L=\sqrt{i^0+\sqrt{i^1+\sqrt{i^2+\sqrt{i^3+\sqrt{i^4+\sqrt{i^5+...}}}}}}$

I just realized my previous answer does not add up.

Since nested radical's have solution's which are real numbers,

hence we consider the value of "L" as real.

@tatan gave equation for "L"

$\ (((L^2-1)^2-i)^2+1)^2+i=L$

Solving for $(i)$ we get:

$(i)=[(L^2-1)^8-4(L^2-1)-L]/[(4(L^2-1)^6-1]$  ---(1)

Since right hand side of equation (1) is real &

the left hand side is imaginary we have a contradiction.

Hence the reply is negative to "OP" question, if a

solution is possible to his given equation.

Comment: Not satisfyied with this answer.

Comment: @MANI. Can you be more specific?. My answer was tailored to the request from "OP". You can always post a similar question suitable to your